# creating a pandas dataframe based on cell content of two other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have wo dataframes with the same number of rows and columns. I would like to create a third dataframe based on these two dataframes that has the same dimensions as the other two dataframes.  Each cell in the third dataframe should be the result by a function applied to the corresponding cell values in df1 and df2 respectively.

i.e. if I have

```
df1 = | 1 | 2 |
      | 3 | 4 |

df2 = | 5 | 6 |
      | 7 | 8 |
```

then df3 should be like this

```
df3 = | func(1, 5) | func(2, 6) |
      | func(3, 7) | func(4, 8) |
```

I have a way to do this that I do not think is very pythonic nor appropriate for large dataframes and would like to know if there is an efficient way to do such a thing?

The function I wish to apply is:

```
def smape3(y, yhat, axis=0):
    all_zeros = not (np.any(y) and np.any(yhat))
    if all_zeros:
        return 0.0
    return np.sum(np.abs(yhat - y), axis) / np.sum(np.abs(yhat + y), axis)
```

It can be used to produce a single scalar value OR an array of values.  In my use case above the input to the function would be two scalar values.  So smape(1, 5) = 0.66.

Comment: sure I edited my post above,

Comment: What is your expected output with this function and these data?

Comment: scalar values.  so I guess the problem really is I have two 2D arrays and I would like to apply a function elementwise to produce the 3rd 2D array.

Comment: What the purpose of calling `smape(1, 5)`, for example? Why does it have an axis parameter when it's taking two integers?

Comment: in that case it would be to produce a scalar value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vectorised approach:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]])

arr = np.where(df1.eq(0) & df2.eq(0), 0, (df2 - df1).abs() / (df2 + df1).abs())

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

print(df)

          0         1
0  0.666667  0.500000
1  0.400000  0.333333
```

Or if you want to separate some of the logic in a function:

```
def smape3(df1, df2):
    return (df2 - df1).abs() / (df2 + df1).abs()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1.eq(0) & df2.eq(0), 0, smape3(df1, df2)))
```